# ggplot line or point plotting conditionally

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot to write a bunch of plots inside a function. I want to pass another flag to the function so that I can choose while calling the function that whether to plot lines or points.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
plot2pdfHD = function(opdata, dir = 'plots'){
  #... do something ...
  plots <- list()

  for (i in seq(strikes)){
    #... do something ...
    plots[[i]] <- ggplot(sset, aes(x = TIMESTAMP, y = value, col = optype)) + 
      geom_line() + labs(x = "Time", y = 'values') + 
      #... do something ...
  }

  pdf(paste0(dir, '/', Sys.Date(), '.pdf'), width=16, height=10)
  for(i in seq(length(plots)))
    tryCatch({print(plots[[i]])}, error = function(e) NULL)
  dev.off()
}
```

I want to add a flag so that by setting appropriate value to the flag I can switch between `geom_line()` and `geom_point()` while calling the function.

Addition:

Can it be done without repeating the additional call part, i.e. `#... do something ...`? I am hoping for an answer that does that.

Also `sset` is a subset of the `opdata`.

Comment: What do you mean by "repeating the additional call part"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for? I like @arvi1000's answer---nice and clear---but you can put the if statement inside a single ggplot addition expression:

```
type = "line"
## also try with
# type = "point"

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + {
      if(type == "point") geom_point() else geom_line()
    } +
    theme_bw()
```

---

For multiple layers, you could do something like this:

```
gg = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg))

{
  if(type == "point") {
    gg + geom_point() 
  } else {
    gg + geom_line() + stat_smooth()
  }
} + theme_bw()
```

(Of course, adding the `theme_bw()` to the original `gg` definition would be cleaner, but this demonstrates that it can be added later.)

Comment: This just hits the target I was looking for, an inline if-else. BTW tried to make it using `ifelse`, didn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: `ifelse` is specially made for vectors, it will always try to return a vector of the same length as the test vector. `ifelse` would try to evaluate `geom_line()` or `geom_point()` by itself and then return the result. `if` is necessary for a use like this.

Comment: If you have more conditions, you could also use `switch`.

Comment: I am using this answer, very nice! But it seems that if you add multiple layers based on 1 condition, you have to build an if(var ==T){..... }+ around each layer or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Mark see edits. Building up a plot object is probably better practice in general.

Comment: @gregor thanks for your response! Do you know why it would be better practise?

Comment: Seems cleaner. If there were an equation where you wanted to add 1 or 2 depending on one condition, you probably would do `x^2 *3 + if(condition) {1} else {2} + foo(x)`. From a practical perspective, you can add geoms to plots, and in a chain `ggplot() + geom_line() + geom_point()` is evaluated left to right: `(ggplot() + geom_line()) + geom_point()`. When you stick the `geom_line() + geom_point()` in the `if` statement, it messes up the associative order.

Answer (score 2):

Plain old `if` block?

```
plot2pdfHD = function(opdata, dir = 'plots', plot_type){

  plots <- list()

  for (i in seq(strikes)) {

    # base gg call
    p <- ggplot(sset, aes(x = TIMESTAMP, y = value, col = optype))

    # add geom layer based on content of argument:
    if(plot_type == 'line')  p <- p + geom_line()      
    if(plot_type == 'point') p <- p + geom_point()

    # add additional params and assign into list item        
    plots[[i]] <- p + labs(x = "Time", y = 'values')

    #...
  }

  # ...
}
```

Other notes:

- I'm assuming you are doing something to make `sset` different before each call, otherwise you are going to get a list of identical plots
- `lapply` might be better than a `for` loop here, esp since you are wanting a list object as the result anyway

Comment: Can it be done without repeating the additional call part? I was hoping for that.   Regarding the `sset`, it's a subset of the `opdata` thats being plotted. So all the plot pages have different plots.